# How do I create an object class with object properties in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, oop, object

I am writing a music related program and want to have objects as properties within my objects. I know it is possible to do one by one, but I would like a shortcut. This is what I want to do, and I know does not work. What is the correct way? Is it possible?

```
function OctaveNote(note, value) {
    this.firstOctave = note + 1.value = value;
    this.secondOctave = note + 2.value = value + 12;
    this.thirdOctave = note + 3.value = value + 24;
}
```

Or

```
function OctaveNote(note, value) {    
    this.firstOctave = note + 1;
    this.firstOctave.value = value;
    this.secondOctave = note + 2;
    this.secondOctave.value = value + 12;
    this.thirdOctave = note + 3;
    this.thirdOctave.value = value + 24;
}
```

So that `C = new OctaveNote ("C", 0);` let me know that `C3.value = 24` and I don't have to write individual objects for each octave of all 11 notes, 99 lines!

Comment: I'm not sure the first would work at all. What is 1.value?

Comment: What do you mean by `C3.value`? Do you mean `C.thirdOctave.value`?

Answer (score 0):

Yes but it need to be objects not a string.

This create a string : `this.firstOctave = note + 1;`

But you can't add the propetry `value` to a string.

So what you need to do is create an object like :

```
// Constructor 
function OctaveNote(note, value) {
    // If we have a note and a value, we add a note.
    if (typeof note !== 'undefined' && typeof value !== 'undefined') this.addNote(note, value);  
}

OctaveNote.prototype.addNote = function(note, value) {
    this[note+1] = value;
    this[note+2] = value + 12;
    this[note+3] = value + 24;
}

var octave =  new OctaveNote("B", 14);
octave.addNote('C', 2);
octave.addNote('A', 6);
console.log(octave.C1); // 2
console.log(octave.A2); // 18
console.log(octave.C3); // 26
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/q7GVs/4/)

Answer (score 0):

Your second example should be one that covers what you need. What you have wrong is the usage/how to call it.

When you create your `C` object with

```
C = new OctaveNote("C", 0)
```

you now have an instance of `OctaveNote` that you can access with all the properties that were set in the constructor function.

So you can get the thirdOctave by calling

`C.thirdOctave.value` which should return `24`.

Your problem here is that `thirdOctave` itself is not an object and so it can't hold properties, like value. You could either convert thirdOctave to an object containing a string and value pair, or you could simply store your value in its own separate property: `thirdOctaveValue`.

So you could transform the function into something like:

```
function OctaveNote(note, value) {
    this.firstOctaveName = note + 1;
    this.firstOctaveValue = value;
    this.secondOctaveName = note + 2;
    this.secondOctaveValue = value + 12;
    this.thirdOctaveName = note + 3;
    this.thirdOctaveValue = value + 24;
}
```

You can then initiate objects for each note:

```
D = new OctaveNote("D", 20);
X = new OctaveNote("X", 32);
```

And get the values out of them:

```
console.log(D.firstOctaveValue);
console.log(X.secondOctaveValue);
```

etc